# TransformerFactoryConfigurationError when trying to use Saxon with a web service

Tags: java, wso2, saxon, transformer-model, wso2-wsas

My web service, living on Axis2 inside a WSO2 WSAS application server, contains the following code:

```
String prop = "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory";
String val = "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl";

public static TransformerFactory getTransformerFactory() {
    System.setProperty(prop, val); // This line executes normally
    return TransformerFactory.newInstance(); // Error occurs inside this call
}
```

When run, the service produces this error:

```
[2013-04-15 12:22:41,263] ERROR
  {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught
  exception
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider
  net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.Setup.getTransformerFactory(Setup.java:40)
        at com.example.ProcessFiles.init(ProcessFiles.java:336)
        at com.example.TorgApp.incoming(TorgApp.java:229)
        ...
```

I do have `Saxon-HE-9.4.jar` in my classpath, and it is readable. It is also available to Axis2 (`/foo/bar/wso2as/wso2as-4.0.0/tmp/axis2-tmp-6436419317930731973.tmp/axis67573163200472779114Saxon-HE-9.4.jar`).

According to [the Javadoc for `newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance%28%29), the system property I'm setting should overrule all other methods of identifying which `TransformerFactory` to use, so precedence is not the issue.

What could be causing this error, and what can I do to get my desired Saxon transformer factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If axis2 (which seems to be the cause of the exception) is placed outside your web application then you must also make Saxon available there too.

Most application servers have a predefined location where jar files can be placed for exactly this purpose.  It will not be enough just to deploy it in your web application.

Comment: Okay, I seem to have been wrong before; I needed to add the JAR to yet another location, `/foo/bar/wso2as/wso2as-4.0.0/repository/components/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a class loading issue. Have you followed this documentation.
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Webapp+ClassLoading